# How can I copy files recursively without overwriting the directories

Tags: linux, unix, cp

On linux, let's say I have some files like this:

```
dir1/file1

dir2/file2
```

and I want to copy them to a destination that already have `dir1` and `dir2` and looks like:

```
dir1/file1

dir1/file1a

dir2/file2

dir2/file2a
```

I want to only replace file1 and file2. But if I do `cp -r`, `dir1` in the destination gets replaced with the contents of `dir1` from the source, as does `dir2`, so I'm left with

```
dir1/file1

dir2/file2
```

in the destination. I lose files `file1a` and `file2a`!

How can I copy in a way that says 'copy any files you find to the corresponding directory if it exists, create a new directory only if necessary and do this recursively'?

Comment: no, you're wrong, cp -r does not delete files, only adds. You're copying them somewhere else.